# python pygame mixer cant open wav file error on mac and pygame is not defined

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I'm using mixer to open file but I get a error. I'm using mac os x.this is my code:

```
mixer.init()
mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
mixer.music.load('Warning.wav')
mixer.music.play()
```

and I get error:

> Couldn't open 'Warning.wav'.

And also when I write `pygame.mixer.init()`, I get error too:

> name 'pygame' is not defined

How can I solve this problem? And also can you change the code for me?
I need solution as fast as you can!

Answer (score 1):

First of all import and initialize pygame. These two lines of code MUST be there.

`import pygame
 pygame.init()`

Now, initialize the mixer.

`pygame.mixer.init()`

Load the music.

`pygame.mixer.load("musicfile.wav")`

Play the music.

`pygame.mixer.play(-1)`

The parameter -1 will tell it to play forever.

You also need to set a screen to a variable.

`gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))`

Here's a fully working example.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("resources\\music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Hope this helped!

NOTE: Pygame works better with .mp3 files for music and .wav files for sound effects.